# Get child count in firebase web

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

is there a way to get the number of children in a firebase node, because I want to perform a loop function. I want to know how many children are there under pictures.

```
   usernames = database.child("Item_features").get()
   for user in usernames.each():
   userid = user.key()
   dtls = database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child('model').get().val()
   if dtls == imodel:

   data = {"picture": picture}

 database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child("picture").push(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for most platforms has a `numChildren` method that returns the number of children under a given snapshot. But as far as I can see in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db) calling `get()` only gives you the JSON from the location, and not metadata such as the number of child nodes. This means you'll have to count them yourself.

Note that on all platforms you will need to read all data to be able to call `numChildren()`, as Firebase has no concept like count queries in SQL. If you want to be able to read only the count, you will need to store that count in the database separately yourself.